# Display table view as layout for android app

Tags: android, layout, tableview

In android application,

How to show multiple row entries in tableview or scrollview for layout for android app in activity file.

Comment: Have you tried adding views to both TableView/ScrollView? For the TableView add TableRow at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add TableRow for table view/scroll view.